# Why is $\beta$ decay a weak force interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, radiation, weak-interaction

In my graduation and also in post graduation, I was told that $\beta$ decay is a weak interaction. But till date I don't know the reason as if why it is a weak interaction process. In my classes some derivations are done, and I am taught some selection rules and difference in the curve of two, beta decay processes, but no where I was told, why one has to consider it a weak interaction configuration.

Comment: The original naming is just an _ad hoc_ deduction. Electrodynamics was known, and stronger than gravitational interaction. That means nuclei should never be possible due to the Coulomb repulsion, unless some much stronger force keeps them together. That _defines_ strong force. Then, some nuclei is found to decay, and that must be something else that occasionally breaks nuclei apart. It must be a rare occurence. That is _defined_ to be the weak interaction. It is why both strong and weak interactions have completely changed character from its original description and still kept their names.

Answer (score 1):

In weak interaction one very important thing is the flavor change in quark level in quark sector, for instance $u \to d$ and also other couplings are possible. The same thing happens for lepton sector also but there the change is a bit different. There $e$ can change to $\mu$ and so on. These happens in mass basis of the Weak Lagrangian. Due to off diagonal entries of $SU(2)$ generators, $\tau_x, \tau_y$, $W_\mu ^{\pm}$ can couple with the other quarks and the coupling constant is determined by the $CKM$ matrix.

Now in case of nuclear $\beta$ decay, we can think it as $p \to n$ or $u \to d$, which is obviously a weak interaction.